# Is there a way to get real time data from IEX?

Tags: python, api, stock

I have just learned to use the [IEX-Cloud-API](https://iexcloud.io/docs/api) but when I print out the results, I only get them by day. And I would like to get them by the minute. My code basically looks like this:

```
start = datetime.date(2020, 12, 20)
df = get_historical_data(stocksymbol, 
                         out_format = 'pandas', 
                         token = api_key, 
                         start = start )
print(df.head())
```

Has anyone got an idea to what I can change in the code so I will get it by the minute, or maybe even in real-time.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to the site! do you want to get the data refreshed per min or get a feed that has per min data(times series). The per min data might be part of the API, the refreshing data in your script may require a infite loop(white = true and a sleep(60) to get the data refreshed.

Comment: Hey, and thanks for welcoming me. When I run this code I get the data from the 5 days after the start date. But I would like to rewrite my code so I get the last values per min.

Comment: You could call the https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#price-only endpoint each minute. There also looks to be a feature where they stream any price changes to you, but that's only available on the paid plan.